# Embed legacy application DOM inside angular application

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm intending to embed a legacy website inside my ng4 application, as temporary transition solution, until the same functionality is implemented in ng4, when old site will be decomisioned. 
Until then, we'd like at least to onboard legacy site clients onto the new ng4 app, and make them access to their legacy service through ng4 app.

The legacy website is based on 20+ years old technology where page is making POST requests to the server, and server is responding with already rendered HTML page, for the browser just to display it. There are no AJAX calls, and there are no cookies. Authentication is done through a login page.
Once authenticated, the security is done based on the encrypted tokens which are in URL of every POST request.

My idea was to build a shell ng4 application which makes calls to the server with AJAX, receives HTML, and injecs it in the ng4's DOM. This gives me control on what I'd like to be shown and what not.
Optionally, I'd like to select some HTML elements in the received DOM (menus that I'd like to hide from user) and remove them, before I inject the received DOM.

In a different approach, my ng4 appliction wouldn't make an AJAX call, but it would have an iFrame which would load the legacy site, and inside onLoad event of the iFrame I would make manipulation of the DOM

Could you please tell me what you think about these approaches, if it would be better to do it differently, and if you know already some open source projects / libs that are doing the similar thing.